# Is there a basic/simple lightbox/overlay jQuery-based library anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, lightbox

Is there any Lightbox-live or overlay library out there that only provides the "basic cross-browser centered popup with a dark background" without attempting to perform requests and display images?

I would like to populate the contents myself using my own JS code which is non-trivial and all of these libraries expecting a link with something displayable inside it are unusable for my simple yet unusual (it would appear) use case...

I've gone over maybe 15 Lightbox clones today and for the life of me couldn't find a simple way to just get the basic overlay functionality without the added fluff. Is anyone familiar with something like that ?

Comment: So you have tried thickbox, etc?

Comment: You can probably just do a simple implementation of your own with css and javascript. Just create a css div for the black overlay and another one for the content and display/hide them as needed using javascript.

Comment: @DeviantSeev That's exactly what I want to avoid. All those lightbox libraries take care of a lot of things that I don't want to develop: cross-browser compatibility, easing, scrolling etc.

Comment: @Jay I did perhaps I missed something with it? It seemed the same. It's also not maintained anymore and the author recommends a bunch of alternatives.

Comment: @AmirAbiri Yes I was just curious to what you have tried? It is pretty pointless to reinvent the wheel on this one. Bren1818 may have the answer here, colorbox looks okay ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Colorbox. Check the Inline Examples. It works well.

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Look here: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ under "Other Content types"

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Dialog in jQuery UI might be an option to consider.

You can customize the download of the library to give you only the dialog.

Just de-select everything from here and select "Dialog" only (it will select the minimum dependencies for you):

http://jqueryui.com/download